# AWN multiple docks, with different settings

Tags: awn

I am able to add a dock in the preferences of the dock I use now (Avant window navigator), but the problem is that the "add new dock" button creates a copy, and if I change something on one dock, then the same exact thing happens to the other dock.

This happens no matter how carefull I am to make different preferences for each dock, they still work as if it is just a copy. I need them to have different things on them, how do I do that?